# How do I add more than ~30 signatures to Apple Mail?

Tags: mail.app, email, signature

I have a lot of signatures, since I like to include witty or insightful quotes at the end of my emails. I was adding them to Apple Mail today and once I get to about 30 or so the list of signatures starts to disappear, like so:
[image: Screenshot of broken Apple Mail signatures]

I tried to work around this by looking for the plist to edit them, but Apple seems to have closed off `~/Library/Mail`, even to the superuser.

I know I can delete signature using the `-` button, and I can still add them using the `+` button, but I can't edit their names.

How might I add more signatures & edit their names?

Comment: Why not use text expander? Then use a namespace like ssig001, ssig002...

Comment: "text expander"?

Comment: More properly "textexpander" at textexpander.com

Comment: I see. Thanks for the suggestion. That doesn't really interest me, though.